# Deriving dates from only day(1,2,3..31), based on Current Date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, select, date-range

Hello SOF community:

I have a table like this

```
 InvoicingActivityStartDay InvoicingActivityEndDay
 27                        26
 27                        26
 01                        NULL --NULL MEANS LAST DAY OF MONTH
 01                        NULL
 15                        14
```

I need a T-SQL query that will return the following for the data above, given the current date; if current date = 12-JAN-2012, the results should be as below

```
InvoicingActivityStartDATE               InvoicingActivityEndDATE
27-DEC-2011 12:00:00.000                 26-JAN-2012 23:59:99.999
27-DEC-2011 12:00:00.000                 26-JAN-2012 23:59:99.999
01-DEC-2011 12:00:00.000                 31-DEC-2011 23:59:99.999
01-DEC-2011 12:00:00.000                 31-DEC-2011 23:59:99.999
15-DEC-2011 12:00:00.000                 14-JAN-2012 23:59:99.999
```

Can you please show me how this be done in a single query?

Please note that if the start day is 1, that means the end day is always the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Is the rule that the start day should be interpreted as that day of last month?

Comment: Need more info. If first col = 2, would you get Dec2-Jan2, or Jan2-Feb2? OR, when does the range returned include CURRENTDATE, and when does it not? Also, what's the second column for? Don't you just need `first col` through `day before first col in next month` as modified by the provided `special rule for 1st of month`?

Comment: The table holds values relative to current date.

If the Invoicing Start Day is 1, then Invoicing End Date is always the end of the Month; if the Invoicing Start Day is other than 1, then the End Day is explicitly mentioned.

For example,today is 13-December-2011. When I run the query today, for rows with Start Day = 1, it should return 1-NOV-2011   30-NOV-2011 (Format doesn't matter).  

If the start day = 27, then the query run today should return, 27-NOV-2011 and 26-DEC-2011

I was able to do this using C# extension methods. But just exploring if it can be done in SQL. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your requirements correctly (that the start day is that day of last month, and the end day is that day of this month; except when start day is 1), then you may want something like this (assuming your start/end days are integers; if not, cast them as ints):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,InvoicingActivityStartDay-1,
                DATEADD(Month,DATEDIFF(Month,0,GETDATE())-1,0))
       AS [InvoicingActivityStartDATE] 
      ,CASE InvoicingActivityStartDay
      WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(ms,-3,
                     DATEADD(Month,DATEDIFF(Month,0,GETDATE()),0))
      ELSE DATEADD(ms,-3,
            DATEADD(DAY,InvoicingActivityEndDay,
                    DATEADD(Month,DATEDIFF(Month,0,GETDATE()),0)))
      END AS [InvoicingActivityEndDATE] 
FROM t
```